# Display count of products in compare list (WooCommerce Products Compare)

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to show the number of actual products on my compare list in WooCommerce.
To compare products, I'm using the plugin WooCommerce Products Compare (https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-products-compare/).

I found no function to display the number of products. But I found the cookie of the plugin and I'm using it to display the count. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $compare_cookie         = $_COOKIE["wc_products_compare_products"];
    $compare_cookie_array   = explode(",", $compare_cookie);
    $compare_cookie_result = count($compare_cookie_array);
?>
<?php if ($compare_cookie_result >= 1) : ?>
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-danger"><?php echo $compare_cookie_result; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

It works fine so far. But I wonder if there is not a better way to display the number of products.

And there is a problem with the reload of the counter. If I add a new product to the list or remove a product from it. The counter stays until I reload or change the page. Is there any way to add an ajax function to change the counter in real time?